# Spring SessionRegistry provides empty session lists when @EnableJdbcHttpSession is used

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-web

Since I persisted the session information of resilient and load balanced spring-boot based microservices to PostgreSQL DB by adding @EnableJdbcHttpSession to our config, the SessionRegistry provides no information at all anymore (e.g. SessionRegistry::getAllPrincipals() empty list).

Also HttpSessionListener is not getting fired anymore.

Grateful for any hint

Frank

Comment: That's a bit thin. Anymore compared to what? If you're using Spring Boot 1.4, you don't need to specify the annotation, just configure the store-type (check the doc).

Comment: Spring Boot 1.3.2, anymore to the state when commenting out @EnableJdbcHttpSession. Sorry I'm new to Spring, will try the store-type.

Comment: You need Spring Boot 1.4 for the store-type thing.

Comment: Unfortunately the behavior is exactly the same using store-type and Spring-Boot 1.4 , session listeners stop to fire and session registry does contain no data. When setting store-type=none these mechanics are working again.

Comment: I think I didn't understand the question then, sorry. You're saying it does not work if you add spring session. And now you're saying that if you disable it (`store-type=none`), it works. A sample project would help I guess.